# Select multiple dates inside Kendo Date Picker widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, kendo-datepicker

I am using kendo date picker widget inside our software application. However, for our specific feature, I would like to be able to select "**more than one date**" inside the date picker widget.

By default, as soon as you change the selected date inside the widget, the widget automatically sets the newly selected date and then triggers the default "**close**" event of the widget and hence, it closes automatically. Therefore, I am not able to handle the "**close**" event manually and hence, the "**change**" event as well. An example of a simple kendo date picker is as under:

```
 $("#inputDateTimePicker2").kendoDatePicker({
                format: "yyyy-MM-dd",
                change: function (e){
                var newValue = kendo.toString(e.sender.value(), "yyyy-MM-dd");                 
                },
                close: function(e){
                //code to handle the close event.
                }
    });
```

Is there a good way to achieve this functionality inside the kendo date picker widget.

It would be very helpful.

Comment: [Asiri Dissanayaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1731855) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67085113) saying "Probably too late to answer. But might be helpful to others. [https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/calendar-select-dates-click](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/calendar-select-dates-click)"